# Cannot access ubuntu server from other machines other than the machine which is hosting the virtual machine which is my ubuntu server

Tags: networking, vmware

I created a ubuntu server on vmware. I am using it as a file server. I can access it if I am connecting through the machine which hosts the virtual machine. I am not able to do it from other machines which are on the same network.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: On virtualbox, you need to set the network interface to bridge. Can you find an option like that in the settings for that vm?

Comment: See [this page](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_bridged_ws.html)

Comment: could you explain what the does? It seems to work now!

Comment: I think Gilles pretty much covered it in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Typical virtual machine software has easy methods to create three types of network interfaces on a VM:

- A bridged network puts the VM on the same network segment as (one of the real network adapters of) the host. Packets sent by the VM are injected onto one of the host's network links and vice versa.
- A [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) network allows the VM to initiate TCP connections to the outside world, but it cannot receive any incoming connections.
- A host-only network connects the VM to a virtual adapter on the host. Connections can only be established between the VM and the host, unless the host acts as a router.

For more information, [read the manual](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_hostonly.html).

It appears that you've created a host-only network. Since you want to access the machine from the outside, create a bridged network instead.